# AWS SQL Server RDS not connecting from godaddy

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, godaddy-api

I have a SQL Server running on AWS RDS. I can connect to SQL Server from my ASP.NET web application running on localhost machine, but when I deploy the same ASP.NET application to Godaddy shared hosting, it is unable to connect to the AWS SQL Server RDS. Security policy on AWS RDS allows inbound traffic to all IP's and VPC is also public.

Below is the error which I get when my website hosted in godaddy tries to connect to SQL Server on AWS RDS

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: My guess would be that the GoDaddy firewall block the outgoing connections. Check their documentation.